# How to find the arguments for torch.nn.conv_transpose2d and max_unpool2d?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

In a given forward function of a convolutional layer I have:

```
def forward(self, x):
  c = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(x)
  a,i = torch.maxpool2d(c)
  o = torch.relu(a)
  return a,i
```

I'm looking to undo this function with `torch.nn.functional.max_unpool2d` and `torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d`.

So far I have (not entirely sure about this either):

```
a = torch.relu(o)
c = torch.nn.functional.max_unpool2d(a, i, kernel_size=c.size[1])
x = torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d(c,..)
```

My questions:

- How come the call to conv2d doesn't require any other arguments than the one given?
- How do I get the parameters for `conv_transpose2d` from only a and i (e. g. from their sizes)? Or is there some other way I'm not seeing?
- Is there a default kernel_size conv2d uses?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my question:

I can access the parameters for `conv_transpose2d` and `max_unpool2d` by using e. g. `torch.nn.functional.conv2d.kernel_size`. The parameter names are stored in the model and can be retrieved via `print(torch.nn.functional.conv2d.features)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments for torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d are slightly different from those for torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d (Functional API).

Please refer to: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#conv-transpose2d for functional API arguments.

torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d initializes the kernel using U[-sqrt(k), sqrt(k)].
On the other hand, you can use your custom (initialized) kernel in torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d.